# Decode option value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have one trouble when i decoded option_value in wp-options table by native php.

My option_value data like:

```
a:4:{s:11:"product_cat";a:35:{i:15;a:16:{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:79:"Tranh treo tường nghệ thuật đẹp - HÀNG NHẬP KHẨU TỪ ĐÀI LOAN";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:198:"Store chuyên cung cấp các mẫu tranh treo tường nghệ thuật đẹp tại HCM. Các mẫu tranh này được tuyển chọn kỹ càng từ các nhà cung cấp uy tin trên thế giới.";s:15:"wpseo_canonical";s:70:"https://xuhuongthietke.com/nhom/do-trang-tri-dep/tranh-treo-tuong-dep/";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:5:"index";s:13:"wpseo_focuskw";s:26:"tranh treo tường đẹp";s:13:"wpseo_linkdex";s:2:"54";s:19:"wpseo_content_score";s:2:"60";s:21:"wpseo_keywordsynonyms";s:4:"[""]";s:21:"wpseo_opengraph-title";s:79:"Tranh treo tường nghệ thuật đẹp - HÀNG NHẬP KHẨU TỪ ĐÀI LOAN";s:27:"wpseo_opengraph-description";s:198:"Store chuyên cung cấp các mẫu tranh treo tường nghệ thuật đẹp tại HCM. Các mẫu tranh này được tuyển chọn kỹ càng từ các nhà cung cấp uy tin trên thế giới.";s:21:"wpseo_opengraph-image";s:84:"https://xuhuongthietke.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/chau-cay-}}}
```

I try:
1> json_decode
2> unserialize

But not working

Comment: unserialize should work

Comment: You have some errors in your serialize data. Check it here - https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html OR https://www.unserialize.com/s/001dee61-13b4-dde8-331e-00003bb18f2e